# mean stack routing for large application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pug, mean-stack

I'm building an application that will be quite large. I'm coming from PHP and jQuery and it might be, that my logic is wrong, please help me.

I'd like to have a custom modular structure, having client folder for frontend and server for backend, with separated views.
Backend is of course built on nodejs, with mongoDb, and jade will be replace with pug, which for now is not very important.

Let's say something like this.

```
├── client
│   ├── clients
│   │   ├── directives
│   │   ├── filters
│   │   ├── main.js
│   │   └── services
│   └── tasks
│       ├── directives
│       ├── filters
│       ├── main.js
│       └── services
├── server
└── views
    ├── clients
    │   ├── form.jade
    │   ├── index.jade
    │   └── list.jade
    ├── clients.jade
    ├── index.jade
    ├── layout.jade
    ├── tasks
    │   ├── form.jade
    │   ├── index.jade
    │   └── list.jade
    └── tasks.jade
```

tasks.jade, clients.jade and index.jade would have have ng-view and js files for a specific purpose. The idea is not to load all js files in index.jade, as I think that would affect performance and it would be cleaner.

index.jade in views would look like this:

```
extends layout

block body
  h1 HTML5 Route Example
  div(ng-view)

  script(src='lib/angular/angular.js')
  script(src='lib/angular-route/angular-route.js')
  script(src='javascripts/app.js')
  script(src='javascripts/services.js')
  script(src='javascripts/controllers.js')
  script(src='javascripts/filters.js')
  script(src='javascripts/directives.js')
```

views/contact.jade

```
extends layout

block body
  h1 HTML5 Route Example - contact
  div(ng-view)

  script(src='lib/angular/angular.js')
  script(src='lib/angular-route/angular-route.js')
  script(src='javascripts/app.js')
  script(src='javascripts/contact/services.js')
  script(src='javascripts/contact/controllers.js')
  script(src='javascripts/contact/filters.js')
  script(src='javascripts/contact/directives.js')
```

views/tasks.jade

```
extends layout

block body
  h1 HTML5 Route Example - contact
  div(ng-view)

  script(src='lib/angular/angular.js')
  script(src='lib/angular-route/angular-route.js')
  script(src='javascripts/app.js')
  script(src='javascripts/tasks/services.js')
  script(src='javascripts/tasks/controllers.js')
  script(src='javascripts/tasks/filters.js')
  script(src='javascripts/tasks/directives.js')
```

And here is the part I'm struggling upon: as partials would be loaded to ng-views of the particular page, I should have routes with redirect, but this way I need a to then load partials and this is not working the way I'd like to.

routing bellow is a very simplified part of the routing I use, actually in real application, it is separated for tasks, clients, ...

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "partials/index",
      controller: "MainController"
    })
    .when("/about", {
      templateUrl: "partials/about",
      controller: "AboutController"
    })
    .when("/contacts", {
      templateUrl: "contacts/index",
      controller: "ContactsController",
      ...
    })
    .when("/contacts/:id", {
      templateUrl: "contacts/list",
      controller: "ContactsController",
      ...
    })
    .when("/tasks", {
      templateUrl: "tasks/index",
      controller: "TasksController",
      ...
    })
    .when("/tasks/:id", {
      templateUrl: "tasks/list.jade",
      controller: "TasksController",
      ...
    })

    ....
    .otherwise( { redirectTo: "/" });
});
```

If I use it this way, those views can be only loaded to views/index.jade, and as mentioned before, I'd like them to be separated, thus I tried this way - using redirects, which doesn't really sound to me to be a good way of doing it:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "partials/index",
      controller: "MainController"
    })
    .when("/about", {
      templateUrl: "partials/about",
      controller: "AboutController"
    })
    .when("/contacts", {
      redirectTo: /contacts
    })
    .when("/contacts/:id", {
      templateUrl: "contacts/list",
      controller: "ContactsController",
      ...
    })
    .when("/tasks", {
      templateUrl: "tasks/index",
      controller: "TasksController",
      ...
    })
    .when("/tasks/:id", {
      templateUrl: "tasks/list",
      controller: "TasksController",
      ...
    })

    ....
    .otherwise( { redirectTo: "/" });
});
```

Is there a different way of doing it? I tried in different ways, but nothing worked as I'd like to.

Please note that this is very simplified intro, and I'm pretty much new to mean stack, still trying to learn best practices.

UPDATED: this app is already running and the first draft can be seen here (it is not modular yet) https://github.com/tesis/meanstack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: it can be solved with lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a common issue when first using the MEAN stack.

The idea is **Backend Routing** vs **Single Page Applications**

So when I load `www.website.com:9000/tasks` you can have your Express in the backend load the the `tasks.jade` file and it will. The page will load and now you are running an Angular application.

Once you are in the Angular application you are using **ngRoute** which gives you the `$routeProvider` ability to route between pages... really what you are doing is loading an single HTML page with no initial content and your web url looks like `www.website.com:9000/tasks/#/` so what you can do is say have it so

```
.when("/about", {
  templateUrl: "partials/about",
  controller: "AboutController"
})
```

which is just saying when the url is `www.website.com:9000/tasks/#/about` that you want to inject the HTML in your special div tag (probably looks like `<ng-view></ng-view>` and this tag is where the HTML is put. The controller is the javascript you want to run on that HTML which allows you to have javascript in two different controllers with the same function names, variables, etc and not have to worry about them conflicting between HTML views.

**Back to the point** - You want to load your `clients.jade` file you will need to "Refresh" the page as you have to go to your Node.js web service, ask/request for the page at `www.website.com:9000/clients` and it will load that whole Angular Single Page Application. This is **NOT** done in the `$routeProvider` part, this is a simple `<a href='/clients'></a>` or in javascript `window.location('/client');`

---

This is more of a **design** question. Do you want the user to open a new page or have them remain on the same page. If you pick the same page then you should have one view in your express layout and just do it all in one Angular application. If you go the new page route then you start to break the reason for ng-routing and just making a bunch of static web pages. Neither is the right answer and it really depends on what you are trying to get done

Comment: @FickerFresh, thanks for your answer. I know that here the logic is different, this application is already running, but what I miss is load another page with all JS related to that page. In the existing application I have one index.html with ng-view, but I'd like to separate those numerous JS files, which is not possible unless I reload the page with nodejs (I don't need window.location for this). As meanstack app is meant to be a SPA app, I tried to separate only footer with JS files, but it didn't work, of course. Thus, I'd had this idea to have separated pages with ng-views

Comment: @AngelM. Jade is an ExpressJS Engine that will literally just take the .jade page you are gonna load, turn it into a string, and replace the syntax is set with normal HTML

if your worry is separating the JS files, you can make a taskController.js and contactController.js file, have them both make a controller that is linked to the angular module and will let you separate them out.

Is that what you are going at?

Comment: @FickerFresh, Jade is a template engine, that is used with PHP, nodejs, etc and you can use it with Angular as well. This app is now running as a meanstack app, but will be also configured for LAMP stack in Laravel (which is using jade as well), so I stick with having same template engine. I already have all those controllers, but what I'm interested in is to separate those JS files out, load them dynamically and here is where I'm struggling at. How would you do that in a module?  I tried to load JS files dynamically, but it didn't work.

Comment: @AngelM. let me make sure I understand the question, is it you want to only load the controllers js files from the server for your webpage to view when the controller is actually used? Like instead of loading them all at once all together

Comment: @FrickerFresh, I updated the code (added content for tasks and contact view). Thus: if I'd click on contact, views/contact.jade should be loaded, clicking on tasks views/tasks.jade should be loaded. I tried to separate modules, created contact module with routing, injected in the myApp module, but this way is not working (of course, as it is treated as a SPA app). Doing it this way, clicking on contact, view/contact/index.jade is loaded, but in views/index.jade instead into views/contact.jade. Is this is possible at all?